# PJMEDIA RFC2833 tone detection

Tags: dtmf, pjsip

Does PJMedia support DTMF and other telephony tone recognition using the "tone" payload format of RFC 2833 ?? Am aware that it does support reception of DTMF in "telephone-event" payload format.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this FAQ about DTMF? http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/FAQ#dtmf

Comment: Yes I have checked it. But the FAQ doesn't say anything about the "audio/tone" payload format(Section 4) of rfc 2833.Am not referring to sending tones through inband means. So does it support sending/receiving  this format?